# Simple Message Handler in Java with generics

Tags: java, generics

I can easily put together a message handling set of generic apis in `C#` with the following quick and dirty code:

```
void Main()
{
    var messageClient = new MessageClient(new TestMessageHandler(), new AnotherTestMessageHandler());

    messageClient.Send(new TestMessage { Information = "Hello TestMessageHandler" });
    messageClient.Send(new AnotherTestMessage { Information = "Hello AnotherTestMessageHandler" });
}


public interface IMessageHandler<TMessage>
{
    void Handle(TMessage message);
}

public class TestMessage
{
    public string Information { get; set; }
}

public class TestMessageHandler : IMessageHandler<TestMessage>
{
    public void Handle(TestMessage message) => 
        Console.WriteLine($"I have handled {message.GetType()} and message is '{message.Information}'");
}

public class AnotherTestMessage
{
    public string Information { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherTestMessageHandler : IMessageHandler<AnotherTestMessage>
{
    public void Handle(AnotherTestMessage message) =>
        Console.WriteLine($"I have handled {message.GetType()} and message is '{message.Information}'");
}

public class MessageClient
{
    private object[] receivers;
    
    public MessageClient(params object[] receivers)
    {
        this.receivers = receivers;
    }
    
    public void Send<TMessage>(TMessage message)
    {
        var messageReceivers = receivers.OfType<IMessageHandler<TMessage>>();
        
        foreach (var messageReceiver in messageReceivers)
        {
            messageReceiver.Handle(message);
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose being to decouple the handling from the message and also the handling from the message initiators.

### Question

What are the best ways to do this in `Java` without having to fight against `type erasure`?  I have spent last few days reading around generics in java, and still have a lot to learn.

#### Thoughts

I have considered the following implementation which is based around a `Map`, however the compiler throws up a warning:

`Warning:(67, 53) Unchecked cast: 'thoughts.dictionarythought.Handles<capture<?>>' to 'thoughts.dictionarythought.Handles<TMessage>'`

```
package thoughts;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class dictionarythought {

    @Test
    public void testReceive() {
        var message = new MyMessage();

        var registrations = new MessageHandlerRegistrations();
        var client = new MessageClient(registrations);

        MyMessageHandler handler = new MyMessageHandler();
        registrations.register(MyMessage.class, handler);


        client.send(message);
        client.send(new MyMessage2());

        Assert.assertEquals(message, handler.lastReceived);
    }



    public class MyMessage {

    }

    public class MyMessage2 {

    }

    public interface Handles<TMessage> {
        void handle(TMessage message);
    }

    public class MyMessageHandler implements Handles<MyMessage> {
        public MyMessage lastReceived;

        @Override
        public void handle(MyMessage message) {
            System.out.println("Received");
            lastReceived = message;
        }
    }

    public class MessageClient {

        private final MessageHandlerRegistrations registrations;

        MessageClient(MessageHandlerRegistrations registrations) {
            this.registrations = registrations;
        }

        public <TMessage> void send(TMessage message) {

            List<Handles<?>> registeredHandlers = registrations.getHandlersRegisteredForMessage(message);

            for (Handles<?> handler : registeredHandlers) {
                // compiler warning here
                Handles<TMessage> concreteHandler = (Handles<TMessage>)handler;
                concreteHandler.handle(message);
            }
        }
    }

    public class MessageHandlerRegistrations {
        Map<Class<?>, List<Handles<?>>> handlers;

        MessageHandlerRegistrations() {
            handlers = new HashMap<>();
        }

        public void register(Class<?> messageType, Handles<?> handler) {
            List<Handles<?>> messageHandlers = handlers.getOrDefault(messageType, null);

            if (messageHandlers == null) {
                messageHandlers = new ArrayList<>();
                handlers.put(messageType, messageHandlers);
            }

            messageHandlers.add(handler);
        }

        public <TMessage> List<Handles<?>> getHandlersRegisteredForMessage(TMessage message) {
            List<Handles<?>> registeredHandlers = handlers.get(message.getClass());

            if (registeredHandlers == null) {
                registeredHandlers = new ArrayList<>();
            }

            return registeredHandlers;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The StackOverflow would be a better fit for your question.